# Internet Explorer code paths when receiveng a Negotiate header

Tags: internet-explorer, dns, active-directory, kerberos, spnego

Is there some kind of documentation on what IE does when receiving a Negotiate Authorize header?

Something like: IE first check if the URL is in the intranet zone. If not it response always a NTLM Authorize.
Then it does a name resolution bla bla
Then it constructs a SPN using this and that and it sends the SPN to its Active Directory. If the SPN not in ACtive Directory it falls back To NTML, etc etc...

Looking into the web I can only see a big compilation of checklists or posibles workarounds or advise like "make sure dns Works properly", but I didn't found any place that explains why the DNS should work properly, ie when and how the IE uses the DNS to decide if it tries Kerberos or NTLM or nothing at all...

I found people stating that Kerberos doesn't work with IP adresses but I don't get why. If DNS reserve works the browser could figure out the name,..

EDITED: I think i'm interested in the algorithm used by SSPI's InitializeSecurityContext (using NEGOTIATE) in order to choose between Kerberos or NTLM as the prefered mechtype. Anyone know if it is documented in some place?

Comment: Not sure why it gets downvoted... Could you add a comment please? I found some RFC documents explaining the SPNEGO, but not sure if they explain in detail all checks and codepath or if these details are implementation dependent...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't get any documentation on Microsoft's internal implemenentation details. All you have is trial and error.